# How to use SUBSTRING With Distinct in sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

My query is

```
select distinct PoNo, PoDate, SupplierId, BillNo
FROM Purchase_Product
order by  PoNo
```

It shows like as follows
[order](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L0YKv.jpg)

But I need PO0001, Po0002, PO0003, PO0004.....

So, i am using

```
select distinct PoNo, PoDate, SupplierId, BillNo
FROM Purchase_Product
order by SUBSTRING(PoNo,5,1)
```

But it shows an error like

> ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is
>   specified. Help me

Answer (score 4):

You can use `GROUP BY` instead:

```
SELECT PoNo, PoDate, SupplierId, BillNo
FROM Purchase_Product
GROUP BY PoNo, PoDate, SupplierId, BillNo
ORDER BY SUBSTRING(PoNo, 5, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also try following one:

```
SELECT PoNo, PoDate, SupplierId, BillNo
FROM (
    select distinct CAST(SUBSTRING(PoNo,2,LEN(PoNo)-2) AS INT) AS Pid, PoNo, PoDate, SupplierId, BillNo
    FROM Purchase_Product
) AS tbl
order by  Pid
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT PoNo, PoDate, SupplierId, BillNo
FROM Purchase_Product
GROUP BY PoNo, PoDate, SupplierId, BillNo
ORDER BY Cast(SUBSTRING(PoNo, 3, len(PoNo)) as int)
```

Extract the number from `PoNo` and orderding by that number.